# error code killed, signal=ALERT al desplegar proyecto asp net core con postgres en CentOS 7

Tags: postgresql, asp.net-core, centos7

Espero que alguien me pueda ayudar. 
Quiero desplegar mi proyecto net core 2.1 en centos 7 pero me marca este error.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hice pruebas con un proyecto básico y todo funciona ok. pero con otro proyecto me salta ese error, esta conectado con postgresql.

este es el log que me sale al ejecutar el comando "sudo systemctl status kestrel-core.service
"
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

a la vez esto me sale al ejecutar el comando journalctl -xe

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¡Hola! Por favor, revisa los logs que genera tu proyecto e inclúyelos en tu pregunta (editándola)

Comment: gracias por responder. ya agregue los logs q me salen

Comment: Esos logs sólo muestran la ejecución del servicio pero no son de tu aplicación. No sabes si genera algún otro log? Puedes probar con `journalctl -xe`. De paso, por favor añádelos como texto, que leer imágenes desde móvil es muy difícil

Comment: gracias Alfabravo. al parecer son unos archivos .exe q talvez esten generando el error. ya agregue el log con el comando journalctl -exe

Comment: Al quitar esos archivos exe, se desplegó el proyecto sin problemas. gracias por tus comentarios.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema se soluciono al quitar unos archivos .exe que se estaban ejecutando en mi proyecto. al quitarlos se desplegó normal en mi servidor CentOS 7.
Este es el comando que me ayudo a identificar el error

```
journalctl -xe
```